# Navigate search links in chromium

Tags: shortcut-keys, chromium

In Firefox if I search for something I can easily navigate through the results by pressing the up and down keys. (A small blue arrow indicates which link is going to be opened if I press enter).

In Chromium however this is not the case, so currently my best option to navigate quickly without the mouse is to search for the words in the link that I want to open and then press ctrl + enter. Is there a faster way of doing this, maybe more like in firefox?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. When asking questions you should be more precise. What do you mean by "search for something". There are several search options in Firefox/Chromium: search within page, search bookmarks, global url bar, Google Search(?). What do you mean ?

Comment: `F3` = navigate to next result; `Shift+F3` = navigate to last result-

Comment: This feature works for me.  I consistently use my up/down arrow keys to select browser options in Chromium.

Comment: Thanks RoVo, sorry for not being precise. I mean Google Search.
Shawn Moore., that is strange, but it confirms my feeling that is used to work fine!  I will try to reinstall Chromium